# Default contact group for new contacts in iOS 10

Tags: iphone, contacts, folders, exchange, group

I use an iOS 10 device together with an Exchange server and several contact folders (some of them shared). When I create a new contact on the phone I have no control in which group it goes and this is really annoying. Back in older versions of iOS, I had the option to set a default group for new contacts (and then manaully sorted them in the correct folder).

Now in iOS 10 my phone is just putting the new contacts in one folder, which in my opinion it has chosen random.

Any idead how the default folder is determined and how i can set a default contact group?

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can do this in settings, then contacts, then default account - change it to whatever account you want!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Comment: Thanks. But I would like to set a default group, not a default account (an account cam have several groups)